# NSURLSessionDataTask failed with error code -999

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am using NSUrlSession for calling backend APIs.
Sometimes the APIs are working but sometimes i am getting the issues like

> *HTTP load failed (error code: -999)*,
>   *HTTP load failed (error code: -1200)*

Refer below :- Screenshot from Xcode logs.
[image]

I have researched regarding it and the possible solutions suggested is to use **App Transport Security Settings** and I am already using it.

Here is the screenshot from **info.plist** file of my project.
[image]

Here below is the code i am using :-

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request uploadProgress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
} downloadProgress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {

} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    NSInteger statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
    completionBlock();
}];

[dataTask resume];
```

So not able to figure out what exactly causing **NSURLSessionDataTask** to fail. 
Even completion block is not called.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you modified the correct `info.plist` ? please check once. I had made the same mistake yesterday.

Comment: Yes its in correct plist file. So kinda stuck with this issue. :(

Comment: @Awesome.Apple Can you give a debug repo with the link you used?

Comment: @trungduc How i can provide you that. Any steps?

Comment: @Awesome.Apple You need to create a new project. Reproduce problem in this project. Upload it to Github or somewhere after that give us link to download this project. I think it will be easier and faster to help you.

Comment: Hi I have created a new project and its working in it. But not in my main project @trungduc

Comment: @Awesome.Apple Seem like problem not related to above code. You should provide more information.

Comment: @Awesome.Apple I have faced a similar issue and it was caused by memory leak I had - the task was failing because it didn't have enough memory to allocate to perform

Answer (score 3):

Error code `-999` is cancelled request, as you're using a wrapper for `NSURLSession`, probably you can't see the correct message.

Anyways, you're instantiating 3 new objects: configuration, manager and data task. None of them has a strong reference in another object (a `UIViewController` for instance), so when you call `[dataTask resume]`, ARC is already removing the reference of your object, because in the concept of sync code, this code is done.

In summary, this is the correct behaviour, to fix that, try to create a `strong` reference of `AFURLSessionManager` in your class and everything will be ok.

Comment: And how to have a strong reference of AFURLSessionManager?

Comment: You mean trying declaring it globally?

Comment: Usually creating a property in that class you're executing this code.

Comment: Tried creating property :-
@property (nonatomic, strong) AFURLSessionManager *manager;

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask;

Comment: But still same issue

Comment: Can you provide a sample project?

Comment: I have implemented Chat third party sdk and also Project size is heavy.
How i would be able to provide demo?

Comment: @Awesome.Apple you can create a new project reproducing the same issue and publish a zip file on dropbox or something.